# VSCode でバイナリファイルを編集したい

Tags: vscode, バイナリファイル

VSCode を使ってバイナリファイルを編集したいです。特に、バイト列を追加したり削除したりしたいです。

[hexdump for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-hexdump) という extension を使うと現状のバイト列を表示したり、既存の 1 バイトを別の値に書き換えることはできるのですが、バイトの追加・削除ができません。この extension の [issue 38](https://github.com/stef-levesque/vscode-hexdump/issues/38) に編集機能の要求が出ているのですが、2018 年 6 月現在 open のままです。

また、VSCode 本体側にも「バイナリを編集したい」という [issue が出ており](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2582)、こちらも open のままです。

VSCode でバイナリファイル / hex ファイルを編集する良い方法はありませんか？

Comment: バイナリエディタはフリーのものも多くあると思うのですが、それではダメなのですか？

Comment: はい、私の環境ではGHexやhexeditなどが利用できますが、単体のバイナリエディタではなく、VSCodeのIDEとしての機能と併用できるエディタとして使いたいため、VSCode上で編集できると嬉しいのです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code 1.44 から [Custom Editor API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors) が実装され、これを活用することで VS Code 1.46 から [Hexeditor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-hexeditor) という拡張機能を入れることでバイナリファイルが編集できるようになりました。

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-hexeditor

というわけで、VS Code の拡張機能タブで「Hexeditor」を検索しインストールすれば、Ctrl / Cmd + Shift + P から Open File using Hex Editor を選ぶことでバイナリファイルとして編集できます！

関連 issue

- [Allow to make edits to binary files](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2582)
- [Hex Editor - Custom Editor API](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98105)